# MVC3. Cache profile for child action. it's impossible now, right?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, attributes, cacheprofile

As I understand it's impossible to setup cache profile for OutputCacheAttribute if action is invoked as a child action.

because of code inside System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute.ValidateChildActionConfiguration()

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CacheProfile) ||
            !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SqlDependency) ||
            !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(VaryByContentEncoding) ||
            !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(VaryByHeader) ||
            _locationWasSet || _noStoreWasSet) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.OutputCacheAttribute_ChildAction_UnsupportedSetting);
        }
```

Is any other ways exist to setup cache profile ?